# H- bridge requirements

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I'm wondering, if in a basic H-bridge, the n, and p type fets need to be the same size, current handling wise.

And why is it quite difficult to find the same size n and p type MOSFETs

Is it enough to just get the p types to big enough to handle the load of a motor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm wondering, if in a basic H-bridge, the n, and p type fets need to be the same size, current handling wise.

No, they don't need to be the same size.

They all need to be sufficiently large to handle the current, both N and P type. As long as its gate capacitance can be driven adequately, a device over-specified for current is not a problem.

> And why is it quite difficult to find the same size n and p type MOSFETs

It's just the way that silicon and its dopants work that N channel FETs are easier to make, and thus cheaper, than equivalently rated P channel types (1). This means they have 90%++ of the market, so benefit from a much wider range being available, and further economies of scale.

Quite often, an H-bridge will use all N channel devices. It's often worth the extra complexity of generating a super-voltage to bias the upper ones to use cheaper, more readily available devices, and standardise on one type of power device throughout.

(1) Germanium was the other way round, P-type transistors were easier to make, and comprised the lion's share of available devices.

Comment: And you don't want a transistor rated for the actual current you're expecting. That usually leads to a fragile, inefficient, hot circuit. You want a current rating several times what you expect to see.

Comment: @JohnDoty Especially if the 'current rating' is the one given on the front of the datasheet for a mosfet... They are buggers for publishing headline figures that rely on the device case being held at 20 Celsius, and mosfets in saturation have a positive temperature coefficient.  If I cannot be bothered to calculate it I generally go for a factor of 10 or so, usually works out ok.